# Why does GCC implement isnan() more efficiently for C++ <cmath> than C <math.h>?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, nan, constantfolding

Here's my code:

```
int f(double x)
{
  return isnan(x);
}
```

If I `#include <cmath>` I get this assembly:

```
xorl    %eax, %eax
ucomisd %xmm0, %xmm0
setp    %al
```

This is reasonably clever: [ucomisd](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_316.html) sets the parity flag if the comparison of x with itself is unordered, meaning x is NAN.  Then [setp](http://www.mathemainzel.info/files/x86asmref.html#setp) copies the parity flag into the result (only a single byte, hence the initial clear of `%eax`).

But if I `#include <math.h>` I get this assembly:

```
jmp     __isnan
```

Now the code is not inline, and the `__isnan` function is certainly no faster the the `ucomisd` instruction, so we have incurred a jump for no benefit.  I get the same thing if I compile the code as C.

Now if I change the `isnan()` call to `__builtin_isnan()`, I get the simple `ucomisd` instruction instruction regardless of which header I include, and it works in C too.  Likewise if I just `return x != x`.

So my question is, why does the C `<math.h>` header provide a less efficient implementation of `isnan()` than the C++ `<cmath>` header?  Are people really expected to use `__builtin_isnan()`, and if so, why?

I tested GCC 4.7.2 and 4.9.0 on x86-64 with `-O2` and `-O3` optimization.

Comment: here is my speculation: pre c99, there is no inline function in c.  no inline function means that functions have to be invoked by jmp/call (or some sort of branching).  __builtin_isnan is not part of c.  it's probably a platform specific intrinsic.

Comment: But surely a system header like `<math.h>` can use platform-specific built-ins.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `isnan` would use `__builtin_isnan` if possible. I see no reason why you would have to call it manually.

Comment: yes it surely can, but things that can be done aren't always done...

Comment: @thang: I tried now with `-std=c99` and it did not help, `jmp __isnan` remains.  Also, I don't think that GCC is required to (or does) actually call all functions naively even before C99; it can implement various builtins to help with performance or otherwise.

Comment: Maybe when C99 came along, no one thought to go back and update isnan

Comment: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15367

Comment: Can't reproduce your findings with `gcc (MacPorts gcc48 4.8.3_0) 4.8.3` as well as `gcc (MacPorts gcc49 4.9.1_0) 4.9.1` on OS X. I always get the sequence `ucomisd %xmm0, %xmm0 ; setp %al` for all cases you have outlined here.

Comment: does anyone think this is related with constantfolding ?

Comment: Interesting. A few weeks ago, I was trying to optimize NumPy's quicksort (in C) by first moving the NaNs out of the way, so that comparisons become cheaper: NumPy defines a custom order where NaN is > any number including inf. Doing this with `(x) != (x)` made quicksort faster. Using `isnan` made it *slower*.

Comment: @larsmans: from my testing it seems that if you say `__builtin_isnan()` you will get the same generated code as `(x) != (x)`...only less portable of course!

Comment: @JohnZwinck NumPy wants to be portable. Strangely, it has its own macro that should become `__builtin_isnan` for GCC, but this still compiled to a function call, even though in a simple test function it *is* inlined.

Comment: This might have something to do with legacy code generation for the FPU.  An expression like (x) != (x) requires a "floating point assist" if x is NaN.  Microcode, 90x slower than the SSE2 version.

Comment: Note that this isn't a gcc issue(gcc doesn't ship a C library), but an issue with the standard C library, glibc in this case.

Comment: @nos: thanks for pointing that out.  I have submitted this as a bug in glibc: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17441

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looking at `<cmath>` for libstdc++ shipped with gcc 4.9 you get this:

```
  constexpr bool
  isnan(double __x)
  { return __builtin_isnan(__x); }
```

A `constexpr` function could be aggressively inlined and, of course, the function just delegates the work over to `__builtin_isnan`.

The `<math.h>` header doesn't use `__builtin_isnan`, rather it uses an `__isnan` implementation which is kind of long to paste here but it's lines 430 of `math.h` on my machine™. Since the C99 standard requires using a macro for `isnan` et al (section 7.12 of the C99 standard) the 'function' is defined as follows:

```
#define isnan(x) (sizeof (x) == sizeof (float) ? __isnanf (x)   \
  : sizeof (x) == sizeof (double) ? __isnan (x) \
  : __isnanl (x))
```

However, I see no reason why it can't use `__builtin_isnan` instead of `__isnan` so I suspect it's an oversight. As Marc Glisse points out in the comments, there is a [relevant bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15367) for a similar issue using `isinf` instead of `isnan`.

Comment: actually, the bug is about isinf.  it's a similar problem with a different function, but it's not strictly the same issue.

Comment: Don't forget to include [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/19109073#19109073) saying that the standard *requires* that they be macros.

Comment: Do you think it would be legitimate to change `<math.h>` to simply say `#define isnan(x) __builtin_isnan(x)`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yeah. I can't think of any reasons why it shouldn't be valid.

Comment: For gcc, it would be valid.  __builtin_isnan isn't there on every compiler.

Comment: But in C++98 mode, `isnan` is inlined too, without a `constexpr`, and GCC has `__inline` in C90 mode.

Comment: @thang: According to the C standard, `<math.h>` is part of the implementation (i.e. part of GCC) so it's technically OK.

Comment: @MSalters: But "the implementation", from the language standard's standpoint, is anything that's *either* the compiler *or* the library. And `math.h` is part of glibc, not gcc... or am I missing something?

Comment: @DevSolar Nothing stops an implementation from using compiler assisted help. For example, in C++'s case there are traits such as `std::is_enum` that require the use of compiler intrinsics to properly implement them. This is okay and there's nothing wrong with it. The only thing the standard dictates is what the implementation interface should look like and what its results are expected. How it does it is just a detail.

Comment: @thang the glibc PR mentions isnan as well, further down. Nobody to copy the obvious workaround `(isnan)(x)`?

Comment: @Rapptz: I've submitted this suggestion as a glibc bug here: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17441