# Is `isnan()` as fast as testing equality?

Tags: c, optimization, nan

In C, is testing if a float is NaN as fast as testing if two floats are equal?  That is is `isnan()` as fast a simple equality test between two floats?

My particular interest is using `gcc` on a standard modern Intel/AMD platform.

Here is a sample piece of C code.

```
#include <math.h>
int main(double x)
{
  return isnan(x);
}
```

Comment: Depends on the compiler. If it generates a function call, it won't be as fast, but if the compiler inlines it then it should be.

Comment: Look at the generated assembly code. And make sure you enable optimization when you compile.

Comment: Related: [Why does GCC implement isnan() more efficiently for C++ <cmath> than C <math.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052640/why-does-gcc-implement-isnan-more-efficiently-for-c-cmath-than-c-math-h)

Comment: Depends on your target architecture and libraries.

Comment: @Olaf Good point. I have tried to clarify.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?  Write a program that does 1,000,000 `isnan` calls and another that does 1,000,000 equality tests and see which program is faster.

Comment: @Barmar How exactly do I look at the assembly. I tried `gcc -O3 -S -o my_asm.s -lm test.c` and `objdump -S --disassemble a.out` but it's not pretty to look at.

Comment: @AndyLester How do  I prevent the compiler from optimizing the loop out?

Comment: @eleanora Access a `volatile` variable in the loop.

Comment: Do you want to compare `isnan(x)` with `x == y` where `y = something;` OR compare `isnan(x)` with `x == y` where `y = NaN;`?  It sounds like you are asking about the first which is odd as that is not equivalent functionality.

Comment: @chux It is the first. The question is if we should use something other than NaN in our code to represent unknown values.

Comment: Is this comparison really causing a performance problem in your application? If not, why are you worrying about it? [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using GCC on x64, `math.h`'s `isnan(float)` compiles to

```
jmp __isnanf
```

Using tail-call optimization, but effectively calling a function. The called function will have to do something equivalent to the code a bit down, at least I don't see any faster way to implement it. That leaves the question how it compares to a comparison unanswered however.

But that doesn't say anything about how fast "testing if a float is NaN" is, because there isn't just the one way to do it. The most direct way,

```
int isnan2(float x)
{
  return x != x;
}
```

Is literally the same thing as comparing floats at the C level. But GCC makes this:

```
xor eax, eax
ucomiss xmm0, xmm0
setp    al
ret
```

Which is not quite the *same* thing as comparing two floats, but close, and in fact a bit faster. Testing for equality means the unordered case tested, as it is here, but then the z flag also has to be tested, like this (from gcc again)

```
xor eax, eax
mov edx, 1
ucomiss xmm0, xmm1
setp    al
cmovne  eax, edx
ret
```

Bonus: using `<cmath>` makes `isnan` compile to the same thing as comparing a float to itself, see the linked question for why.

[Godbolt link for convenience](http://goo.gl/9grsK7)

I now see you actually had `double`, but that doesn't change anything qualitatively.

Comment: Thank you for the very nice disassembly. Do you know if `x!=x` is supposed to work in all compilers?

Comment: @eleanora no, because not all of them even support NaN. There are platforms that just don't have NaNs (like TI-83+, some DSPs, etc). Also it doesn't work if you use -ffast-math or some of the related options - they break all sorts of things including usually this.

Answer (score 2):

For GCC (and perhaps Clang as well), the catch of optimizing `isnan()` function call is whether signaling NaNs are present in the code, and whether floating point exceptions would be raised on encountering a signaling NaN.

GCC assumes `-fno-signaling-nans` by default and so `isnan(x)` can be safely optimized into `(x != x)`, which, on x86 with SSE2, would translate into a UCOMISS or UCOMISD instruction.

Setting [`-fsignaling-nans`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fsignaling-nans) disables such optimization.

ISO/IEC TS 18661-1 (which is incorporated into the upcoming C23 standard) clarified the behavior of `isnan()` that the function never throws any exception, even when the argument is a signaling NaN. (This make it irony that the "signaling" NaN in IEEE 754 doesn't always signal.)

The `(x != x)` expression, on the other hand, *does* throw [FE_INVALID](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/FE_exceptions) exception (aka. "Invalid Operation") when `x` is a signaling NaN.

Here is a quick comparison table for behaviors of various expressions with "quiet" NaNs and "signaling" NaNs:

```
              | isnan(x) | (x != x)  | (x >= x)   | isgreaterequal(x,x)
--------------+----------+-----------+------------+--------------------
-Wfloat-equal | no warn  | warn      | no warn    | no warn
--------------+----------+-----------+------------+--------------------
Finite number | false    | false     | true       | true
Infinity      | false    | false     | true       | true
NaN (quiet)   | true     | true      | FPE; false | false
SNaN          | true     | FPE; true | FPE; false | FPE; false
```

Notes:

- `isnan()` and `isgreaterequal()` technically return values of `int` type, not `bool`. The "true" and "false" in the table correspond to nonzero and `0` values, respectively.
- "FPE" in the table indicates a floating point exception would be thrown;
  specifically the "Invalid Operation" exception.

If your application code does not use signaling NaNs at all (or you use them only for debugging), then you might define a macro for a "cheaper" `isnan` which won't emit calls to the libm `isnan()` function:

```c
#include <math.h>
#ifdef isgreaterequal
#define isnan_cheap(x) (!isgreaterequal(x, x))
#endif
```

As `isgreaterequal` macro is type generic in C, this custom macro would be type generic as well.

Comment: Personal note: I wrote [an optimization patch for htop](https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/pull/1271) to replace `isnan` with a cheaper function, while getting a detailed knowledge of this.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is if we should use something other than NaN in our code to represent unknown values.  ([OP comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922103/is-isnan-as-fast-as-testing-equality/33923591#comment55607692_33922103))

Then you should compare `isnan(x)` with `x == some_constant`.  If that `some_constant` did not have a value of 0 or NAN, then the compare could simply be a bit compare if using typical FP representation - hard to beat that by much for speed.

Still, NaN is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

No. The equality test is inline so you pay the price of a function call overhead calling isnan(). But equality can't be used w/o IEEE, so ...

Comment: Not if the compiler inlines it.

Comment: Which only makes it just as good ... But then again that's not always applicable even on a compiler that can normally inline things.