# Does GCC's __builtin_isnan do something other than isnan?

Tags: gcc, floating-point, c99, built-in, isnan

In the [GCC built-ins description](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), it says:

> GCC provides built-in versions of the ISO C99 floating-point comparison macros that avoid raising exceptions for unordered operands. They have the same names as the standard macros ( isgreater, isgreaterequal, isless, islessequal, islessgreater, and isunordered) , with _*builtin* prefixed. We intend for a library implementor to be able to simply #define each standard macro to its built-in equivalent. In the same fashion, GCC provides fpclassify, isfinite, isinf_sign, isnormal and signbit built-ins used with _*builtin* prefixed. The isinf and isnan built-in functions appear both with and without the _*builtin* prefix.

So, I'm not quite able to parse this. When should floating-point comparisons raise exceptions? Does the C standard mandate they do? Mandate they don't? Doesn't mandate anything? And - does `__builtin_isnan()` act differently than `isnan()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC's builtins of standard library functions are mostly for optimization, when certain arguments or environment constraints can be known at compile time. `__builtin_isnan()` works in the similar fashion.

The main purpose of `__builtin_isnan()` is to permit optimizing `isnan(x)` into `(x != x)` when signaling NaN support is disabled (i.e. [`-fno-signaling-nans`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fsignaling-nans), which is the default).

The behaviors of `isnan(x)` and `(x != x)` are not identical. There are differences when a signaling NaN is being evaluated.

(Above is the main answer to the question. Below are more technical details.)

---

IEEE 754 (the standard) defines "quiet" NaNs and "signaling" NaNs that could be a headache for you to get them thoroughly. (I mean it.)

If you are new to IEEE floating points and their compare operations, here are some basics:

- There are four possible results (or relations) for comparing two IEEE 754 floating points: "less than", "equal", "greater than" and "unordered". The "unordered" result happens when either or both operands are NaNs. This also means that `!(x > y)`, for example, is not equivalent to `(x <= y)` in floating points. (However `!(x == y)` and `(x != y)` are equivalent.)
- IEEE 754 defines "quiet" and "signaling" compare operations, with the difference being whether and when they would generate floating point exceptions.

The "quiet" and "signaling" terms are relative, and I add them in scare quotes because a "quiet" compare isn't always quiet, and "signaling" doesn't always signal.

The "quiet" comparisons in IEEE 754 map to these in C: `(x == y)`, `isgreater`, `isgreaterequal`, `isless`, `islessequal`, `isunordered`.

The "signaling" comparisons in IEEE 754 map to these in C: `iseqsig`, `(x > y)`, `(x >= y)`, `(x < y)` and `(x <= y)`. There is no "signaling" variant of `isunordered` as that won't make sense.

For "quiet" comparisons they don't throw FP exceptions with a quiet NaN operand. *But* they do throw "Invalid Operation" ([FE_INVALID](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/FE_exceptions)) exception when any of the operands is a signaling NaN.

For "signaling" comparisons they throw exceptions when any of operands is a NaN, regardless of its signaling bit. (I.e. they throw exceptions on quiet NaNs, too.)

Then there are functions that never throw exceptions, even with the presence of a signaling NaN. `fpclassify` functions, including `isnan`, are this kind. (These are also standard operations in IEEE 754, although different languages provide different APIs for these.)

In [this Stack Overflow answer about isnan() and (x != x)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77654456/4606310) I made a quick comparison table:

```
              | isnan(x) | (x != x)  | (x >= x)   | isgreaterequal(x,x)
--------------+----------+-----------+------------+--------------------
-Wfloat-equal | no warn  | warn      | no warn    | no warn
--------------+----------+-----------+------------+--------------------
Finite number | false    | false     | true       | true
Infinity      | false    | false     | true       | true
NaN (quiet)   | true     | true      | FPE; false | false
SNaN          | true     | FPE; true | FPE; false | FPE; false
```

*Notes: `true` and `false` in the table refer to the nonzero and `0` return values respectively for the macros (their return types are `int`, not `bool`). "FPE" indicates that the macro or expression produces "Invalid Operation" exception.*

So you can get the idea on how `isnan`, `!=`, `>=`, and `isgreaterequal` behave on different kind of floating point values.

Comment: Related: [GCC bug report 66462](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66462). Sometimes GCC optimizes `__builtin_isnan()` when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

By exception here, the GCC docs refer to [IEEE 754 floating point exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Floating_point_exception). If you do something like

```
a < b
```

and one of the operands is a NaN, an FP exception (invalid) will be raised. That means a bit in the FPU will remain set until it's explicitly cleared by the programmer. By instead using `isgreater`/`isless`/etc. the programmer can avoid triggering the FP exception.

Comment: So, the "exception" text only regards LT/GT/LTE/GTE, and not anything else? i.e. not isnan ?

Comment: Yes, my interpretation of the text you quoted is that GCC provides the other builtins so that standard library implementations can use it, and the exception part applies only to the comparisons.

Comment: Interpretation is fine, but... I want to know this for certain.

Comment: If you want something more authoritative than the docs I suggest you write up a few small test programs and see how it behaves and what kind of ASM it generates, or look at the compiler sources (I'd guess the first place to look for would be grepping for BUILT_IN_ISNAN in gcc/builtins.c).

Comment: Good idea. I made the mistake of trying to look isnan() up in the glibc sources and gout discouraged :-(

Comment: (To be fair, neither glibc nor gcc sources are particularly easy to get into as an outsider)

For an example test program and the ASM generated, see e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/54Er63aPc